# Using Cassandra with PHP 7.1

Tags: php, cassandra

From the research I've done, https://github.com/datastax/php-driver/ seems to be the best option for using Cassandra with PHP.

However when I try to install it, I get the error: `pecl/cassandra requires PHP (version >= 5.6.0, version <= 7.0.99), installed version is 7.1.4-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1`

I tried installing https://github.com/aparkhomenko/php-cassandra but it didn't work, giving this error: `warning: Could not find remote branch deprecated to clone.
fatal: Remote branch deprecated not found in upstream origin
Unexpected end of command stream`

I tried http://evseevnn.github.io/php-cassandra-binary/ but it seems like Cassandra 3.1 isn't supported

Is there any way to use Cassandra with PHP 7.1? I'm willing to go back to PHP 7.0.x if necessary, but I'd like to avoid doing that if possible.

Thanks to anyone who can help

Answer (score 0):

Currently the DataStax PHP driver for Apache Cassandra does not support PHP v7.1.x (only versions 5.6.x and 7.0.x). There is a JIRA ticket ([PHP-155](https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/PHP-155)) to add support; contributions are always welcome.